# ¿Cómo pasar datos de un formulario a un controlador laravel con ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo un formulario de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi controlador laravel es el siguiente:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            return $this->sendResponse($name, 'se actualizo la informacion correctamente');   
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->sendError($e , 'ocurrio un error en el servidor');
        }    
}
```

el response es para ver como me devuelve la data.

esta es mi ruta:

```
Route::get('completeregister/{request}', 'Auth\RegisterController@store');
```

este mi codigo ajax:

```
 function updateDataRegister(){
  let formElement = $('#formvalidateregister');
  let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formvalidateregister"));
  $.get( "http://me.pruebalocal.com:8000/completeregister/"+formData, {},
  function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
  });  
}
```

pero no me retorna los datos del formulario.

Como puedo hacer para pasar los datos del formulario como si fuera un obejeto y poder utilizarlo el laravel, sin tener que pasar cada dato como parametro individual

Comment: No se muy bien lo que intentas conseguir, tal vez quieras crear un usuario mediante ese formulario? deberías usar la clase que quieras utilizar como modelo y utilizar el helper de $request, donde se almacenan todos los datos enviados. Prueba esto para que veas como funciona: `dd($request);` en tu controlador

Comment: ¿cuál es el fin de llamar `{request}` al parámetro? eso es un poco extraño.